# Adding a sequence of one hundred numbers to a starting number

Tags: text-processing, awk, numeric-data

If I have file like this:

```
1  
19  
24  
119  
201  
230
```

... then I want output like this:

```
1 2 3 4 .........100  
19 20 21 22 .......119  
24 25 26 ...........124  
119 120 121 .......219  
201 202 203.........301  
230 231 231 ........ 331
```

Each row starts with a particular number; I want to increment that number until 100 with gap of 1.

Comment: I might point out that you've added only 99 to the first (`1`) row and 101 to the `230` rows in the output.

Comment: Do you really mean "_I want to increment that number until 100_", which is not what your examples show, or should it be "_I want to increment that number 100 times_" to match what I think your examples intend to show?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ for (i=0;i<100;i++) printf("%d ",$1+i); printf("\n"); }'
```

Smells like homework to me.

Comment: Small points but - `print ""` is more robust than `printf("\n")` as it'll work for any setting of `ORS`, your loop will put a trailing blank at the end of every line and the final `;` is redundant. It should really be `{ for (i=0;i<100;i++) printf "%d%s", $1+i, (i<99 ? OFS : ORS) }` or slightly more efficiently `{ printf "%d", $1; for (i=1;i<100;i++) printf "%s%d", OFS, $1+i; print "" }`.